# On the Dimensionality of Space: An Elementary Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The below theorem I am to prove. Perhaps you have a critique...

---

**Theorem 2.4** Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be two subspaces of a vector space $V$. Then $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)=\dim(W_1)$ if and only if $W_1 \subset W_2$.

---

My—perhaps lazy—attempt to prove it... I say lazy in the sense that I don't show $\subseteq$ then $\supseteq$.

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be finite subspaces of the vector space $V$. Let
\begin{eqnarray}
\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_l\}
\end{eqnarray}
be a basis for $W_1 \cap W_2$. Because $W_1 \cap W_2 \subset W_1$, then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_l,\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_m\}
\end{eqnarray}
as a basis for $W_1$, and similarly we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_l,\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\dots,\gamma_n\}
\end{eqnarray}
as a basis for $W_2$, so $W_1+W_2$ is spanned by the linearly independent set of vectors
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_l,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m,\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n
\end{eqnarray}
and has dimension $l+m+n$. Thus, from (14) and (15) we have that $\dim W_1 = l+m$ and $\dim W_2 = l+n$, so
\begin{eqnarray}
\dim W_1 + \dim W_2 & = & (l+m)+(l+n) \\
&=&l+(l+m+n) \\
&=&\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) + \dim(W_1+W_2).
\end{eqnarray}
This being the case, then the second statement in Theorem 2.4 implies that $\dim W_2 = \dim (W_1+W_2)$, or $l+n=l+m+n$. This means that $m=0$, which implies that the basis for $W_1$ has the form
\begin{eqnarray}
\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_l\},
\end{eqnarray}
so since $W_2$ has the form
\begin{eqnarray}
\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_l,\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n\},
\end{eqnarray}
then it is clear that this can only be the case when $W_1 \subset W_2$.

Comment: I really don't see why you keep tagging questions with [elementary-set-theory].

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sets are involved. I want non-topic-specific insight. Ideas from other regions of thought slosh over to others. Insight through these other regions are necessary. Have you heard of the Ketengban tribe? Perhaps understanding their methods of ornithological identification could help simple-minded people have a deeper mode of classification. I don't know that I'm really getting my point across here...

Comment: Then perhaps tag it using [english-written-problems] as well, seeing how English is involved?

Comment: I can't yet. My "reputation" isn't high enough. ^_^

Comment: Someone with a more purely set-theoretic background would perhaps have a stronger insight into the problem than one focused primarily with the other tags... That's all...

Comment: It's a misleading tag. End of discussion.

Comment: Not necessarily. The tags should suggest something about the content of the question (or the answers), and not about who you wish to attract to the question.

Comment: Oh, OK, so potential-attraction tags are disallowed on this website then, yes? Well, I am still under the impression that this question has quite a bit to do with set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how well is one acquainted with these things I'd prove this much shorter and using basic set theory:

$$W_1\subset W_2\iff W_1\cap W_2=W_1$$

and thus for finite dimensional *vector subspaces*:

$$W_1\subset W_2\iff \dim(W_1\cap W_2)=\dim W_1$$

Comment: I'm fairly unacquainted with "these things," and I think that will always be the case... Even for everyone else on the planet too, don't you think? I mean in a Feynman kind of way...

Comment: It is for an honors class, so I assume it must be detailed...

Comment: Well, it is not the most usual thing to see someone trying some basic exercises in linear algebra **without** some basic set theory...

Comment: Oh, and the above is *very* detailed...and honor class in high school, college, university...?

Comment: UC... Tell me about it! This Honors Linear Algebra course is "supposed" to be our introduction to proofs...

Comment: I don't know what UC is...University of California, of Carolina, of Curdistan, United Colors...? Anyway, do you know the basic set theory I wrote about? I think you **must** know as you used basic set theory notation in what you wrote.

Comment: I find it so funny that you have a two-line argument... Do you think that would suffice? I mean, what you wrote? Furthermore, do you think that mine would suffice? Does it make sense? Is there anything you think that could make it better?

Comment: Yes, University of California. I forget that people view this site from all over the world.

Comment: I don't really have much experience with the ilk of those theories... Perhaps you have a good source to recommend that I could use that has ideas I couldn't possibly produce under my own design as quickly as having them would be.

Comment: Of course it suffices, but I can't swear it'll suffice *in your case* (your lecturer could expect something else...I can't say). Anyway, you use some rather important theorems in linear algebra, like "every linearly independent set can be completed to a base". BTW, what does "a honor class" mean? Is that an advanced students class or what?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole idea. Here, I'm under the impression, "honors classes" means "more insight classes," so I take them. They are hard, but I take them anyway.

Comment: I think the only two things you really need to fully understand my answer are: (1) for two sets $\,A,B\,$ , we have that $\,A\cap B=A\iff A\subset B\,$ , and (2) for two vector subspaces of the same vector space $\,U,V\;$ with the condition that one's contained in the other, we have that $\;\dim U\le \dim V\iff U\subset V\,$ . In both cases above, the containment $\,\subset\,$ is *weak* , meaning: it can properly be contained in or be equal to.

Comment: My pleasure....